# Ionic 2 - new tab bar disappearing after switching from one module to another

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page in one module that contains a tab bar like so:

ModuleTab.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Scanner" tabIcon="qr-scanner"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab> 
</ion-tabs>
```

Within this module (ModuleTabs) , I have a page (Scanner) that pushes another page contained within another module that has different tabs (OtherModuleTabsPage).

Scanner.ts

```
root.push(OtherModuleTabsPage, { "data": data });
```

Now, OtherModuleTabsPage is contained in another module that has different tabs all together (different number of tabs, Icons and so on).

OtherModuleTabsPage.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="apps" [rootParams]="id"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="close"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So the issue is that once the OtherModuleTabsPage is pushed and the new page is opened, the new tabs bar is hidden. However when I navigate to another page from let's say tab1Root (which is linked to a page within the module) and press the "back" button on the navbar, the tabs appear.

I tried using `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { tabsHideOnSubPages :false })` in app.component.ts but it still does't do the trick
How do I keep the new tabs from disappearing when I navigate to the module without them disappearing?

Thank you